# How to get the value from previous page to another page and keep it as hidden in the current page using Struts?

Tags: java, html, forms, struts-1

I have developed one page to get the value 'username, password, profession' and I have stored this value in DynaActionForm.

And I'hv designed another page to get some other information from the end user. As well as wants to get the previous page value  and keep it as hidden in the current page. But it showing error in the browser.

My second jsp page code is :

```
<%@ taglib prefix="html" uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html" %>
<HTML>
    <BODY BGCOLOR="pink">
           <CENTER>
                <H1>Please fill the following things to complete the registration</H1>
                <html:form action="register2" method="POST" > 

<html:hidden property="name" value="%{registerform1.name}" /> 
                       <html:hidden property="password" value="%{registerform1.password}" /> 
                       <html:hidden property="profession" value="%{registerform1.profession}" />

                       Cell:<html:text property="cell"/>
                               <FONT SIZE="3" COLOR="red">
                                             <html:errors property="cell"/>
                                 </FONT><BR>
                       Gender:<html:radio property="gender" value="male">male</html:radio>
                                    <html:radio property="gender" value="female">female</html:radio> <br><br>
                                    <FONT SIZE="3" COLOR="red">
                                             <html:errors property="gender"/>
                                 </FONT><BR>
                        <html:checkbox property="agree" value="true"/>I agree the terms and condition of this registration <br><br>
                                 <FONT SIZE="3" COLOR="red">
                                             <html:errors property="agree"/>
                                  </FONT><BR>
                        <html:submit>Complete Registration</html:submit>
                </html:form>
           </CENTER>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Please suggest how to solve it. 
Thanks,
Ashok

Comment: *"But it showing error in the browser."*  Pretend we are not sitting in front of your browser.  What error?

Answer (score 0):

The variables names in jsp  must be equal to the action fields.Then only it will populate automatically

Comment: The Exception is                               javax.servlet.ServletException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /register2.jsp(8,28) No tag "bean" defined in tag library imported with prefix "html"
 org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:286)
 org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
 org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:462)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)